# upload image in public directory in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for add Hotel And I Want to select image for AnyHotel I use Ajax to save image directory But I Can not upload image in `public\images` Directory,My Code is Here
in Blade:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <input type="file" id="image">
</div>
<button type="submit"data-dismiss="modal"
id="AddHotel">Add hotel</button>
<script>
$('#AddHotel').click(function (event) {
        var image = $('#image').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        $.post('/Add/Hotel', {
                'image' : image,
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
            },
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            });
    });
</script>
```

And in Controller to save image directory I'm using this code:

```
public function Store(request $request)
{
    $hotel->image = $request->image;
    $hotel->save();
    return $request->all();
}
```

My Problem is here That When I Print this image from DB image should be in public Directory,How I Can upload image in directory?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel stores files in the storage directory by default. You can create a symlink as described here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk, or create another disk in your filesystems config file.

The former is probably your better option.

Comment: Please Show in Code I'm new in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel helper functions to specify the directly:

Example:

```
$currentUser = \Auth::user();
$save_path = storage_path().'/users/id/'.$currentUser->id.'/uploads/images/hotel/';
```

Then to retrieve the image you can make a method like:

```
public function userHotelImages($id, $image)
{
    return Image::make(storage_path().'/users/id/'.$id.'/uploads/images/hotel/'.$image)->response();
}
```

And to call that method and give it a route in `web.php`

```
// Route to show user avatar
Route::get('/user/{id}/images/hotel/{image}', [
    'uses' => 'YourControllerFileName@userHotelImages',
]);
```

But adjust all routes and paths to your liking.

Here are some references to this approach in use that I Put the above examples together from:

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProfilesController.php#L274

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/routes/web.php#L91

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
  <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
  </div>
 <button type="submit" id="AddHotel">Add hotel</button>  
</form>

 // saving to db
$image = $request->file('image');
$hotel->image = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$hotel->save();

// this will upload your image to public/images directory
\File::move($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], public_path('images/'.$image ));  
return response()->json(['status' => 'true']);
```

You cannot send image from ajax in the way you are sending right now. Submit data like below.

```
$('#AddHotel').click(function (event) {
    var your_data= new FormData();

    var city = $('#city').val();
    your_data.append('city',city);
    your_data.append('_token',$('input[name=_token]').val());

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"/Add/Hotel",
    data:your_data,

    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    } 
 });
```

Normally this will do. But you can use package called intervention for various operation like resizing. You can find here http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: I'm used your answer But I give this Error `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"`

Comment: Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form ? Your input type should have name on it and for this code it should be name='image'

Comment: please help me I use Bootstrap modal where I can use form?

Comment: You just need to include your form inside the modal like <div class="modal-body"> your form </div>.